# Dropzone.js + Jquery UI sortable queue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dropzone.js

I've discovered how I could make user change dropzone queue, but it changes only display of the files and I get error **"Uncaught TypeError: queue.forEach is not a function"**. How I could make this to work?

```
$("#demo-upload").sortable({
    items: '.dz-preview',
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.5,
    containment: '#demo-upload',
    distance: 20,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    stop: function () {
        var newQueue = '';
        var queue = dd.files;
        $('#demo-upload .dz-preview .dz-filename [data-dz-name]').each(function (count, el) {
            var name = el.getAttribute('data-name');
            queue.forEach(function (file) {
                if (file.name === name) {
                    newQueue.push(file);
                }
            });
        });

        dd.files = newQueue;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a solution to this and I found the exact implementation in this CodePen project.
[Link to the implementation (Dropzone.js + jQueryUI Sortable)](https://codepen.io/malkafly/pen/gbVYZb)

The HTML

```
 <form action="/upload" class="dropzone" drop-zone="" id="file-dropzone"></form>
    <ul class="visualizacao sortable dropzone-previews" style="border:1px solid #000">

    </ul>
<div class="preview" style="display:none;">
  <li>
    <div>
    <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
      <img data-dz-thumbnail />
    <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
    <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
    <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
    <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </li>  
</div>
```

The CSS

```
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/min/dropzone.min.css');
.sortable {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.sortable li {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;  
    text-align: center;
    margin:5px;
}
li.sortable-placeholder {
    border: 1px dashed #CCC;
    background: none;
}
```

The JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.sortable').sortable();

});

//DropzoneJS snippet - js
$.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/min/dropzone.min.js',function(){
  // instantiate the uploader
  $('#file-dropzone').dropzone({ 
    url: "/upload",
    maxFilesize: 100,
    paramName: "uploadfile",
    maxThumbnailFilesize: 99999,
    previewsContainer: '.visualizacao', 
    previewTemplate : $('.preview').html(),
    init: function() {
      this.on('completemultiple', function(file, json) {
       $('.sortable').sortable('enable');
      });
      this.on('success', function(file, json) {
        alert('aa');
      });

      this.on('addedfile', function(file) {

      });

      this.on('drop', function(file) {
        console.log('File',file)
      }); 
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Comment: There is dropzone.js which lets you drag and drop elements like images or other files for upload from your computer, and there is jquery UI sortable which lets you sort html elements by dragging. After you drag and drop files/images from your computer they get arranged in the order in which you dropped them. So the question was how to arrange them accordingly. In the codepen link I posted, the same has been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

After having put a lot of hours into this I finally have a solution to make jquery sortable work with dropzone.js. I'll put the script of interest first and the full dropzone js script second. The commentary should explain what is happening.

First you need this function

```
//the function for replacing the array
    function newDropzoneArray(oldArray){
        // on the webpage search for all the images that have been uploaded
        var imageTags = $('#myDropzone').find('div.dz-image img');

        // the new array where we will put in the new files
        var current_queue = [];

        // iterate through all the images that have been uploaded by the user
        imageTags.each(function (index, imageTag) {
            // get the image name from the images
            imageName = imageTag.alt;

            // now we will iterate through the old array
            for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
                /** if the name of the image on the website is the same as the image from the old array
                 * we will add it to the new array. You can see this as sorting the array.
                 */
                if (imageName === oldArray[i].name) {
                    current_queue.push(oldArray[i]);
                }
            }
        });
        // now we return the new dropzone array so that we can replace it.
        return current_queue;
    }
```

Then in your init look for the //! important part //

```
    init: function() {
    // very important to make the sortable work
    var myDropzone = this;

    // In your drop zone you have your click handler event
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
        e.preventDefault();

        //here we replace the array with the new one
        //! IMPORTANT PART IS HAPPENING HERE.
        myDropzone.files = newDropzoneArray(myDropzone.files);

        // dropzone will now submit the request
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
```

if you are interested in the full dropzone js script:

```
$("#myDropzone").sortable({
    opacity: 0.7,
});

//the function for replacing the array
function newDropzoneArray(oldArray){
    // on the webpage search for all the images that have been uploaded
    var imageTags = $('#myDropzone').find('div.dz-image img');

    // the new array where we will put in the new files
    var current_queue = [];

    // iterate through all the images that have been uploaded by the user
    imageTags.each(function (index, imageTag) {
        // get the image name from the images
        imageName = imageTag.alt;

        // now we will iterate through the old array
        for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
            /** if the name of the image on the website is the same as the image from the old array
             * we will add it to the new array. You can see this as sorting the array.
             */
            if (imageName === oldArray[i].name) {
                current_queue.push(oldArray[i]);
            }
        }
    });
    // now we return the new dropzone array so that we can replace it.
    return current_queue;
}

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

// Configuration
url: '../somewhere',
method: 'post',
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: true,
parallelUploads: 100,
maxFiles: 100,
addRemoveLinks: true,
// The setting up of the dropzone
init: function() {
    // very important to make the sortable work
    var myDropzone = this;

    // In your drop zone you have your click handler event
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
        e.preventDefault();

        //here we replace the array with the new one
        myDropzone.files = newDropzoneArray(myDropzone.files);

        // dropzone will now submit the request
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
    this.on('completemultiple', function(file, json) {
    });

    this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
        formData.append("name", jQuery("#name").val());
        formData.append("sample1", jQuery("#sample1").val());
    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
        // redirecting user on success. No message atm.
        var url = document.location.origin + "/somewhere_to_redirect";
        window.location.replace(url);
    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
        // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
        // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
    });

}

}
```